# How to insert hardcoded value for a field into the database whenever button is clicked?

Tags: c#, forms, insert, window

Inside my appointment table i have aDate, aTime, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, patientID, mcID and aStatus fields. aDate, aTime, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, patientID, mcID values will be entered via textbox and inserted into database, but only for aStatus field I want it auto insert this value called (waiting) for aStatus field into the appointment table whenever the create button is clicked, how to do that for aStatus?

```
protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                Guid guid;
                guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                string sql = "INSERT INTO appointment (aDate, aTime, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, patientID, mcID)";
                sql += "VALUES (@aDate, @aTime, @aContact, @aHeight, @aWeight, @patientID, @mcID)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aDate", txtDate.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aTime", txtTime.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aContact", txtContact.Value.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aHeight", txtHeight.Value.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aWeight", txtWeight.Value.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientID", txtpatientID.Value.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcID", txtmcID.Value.Trim());

                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

               // Session.Add("Username", txtFirstName.Value);
              //  Session.Add("Password", txtContact.Value);
              //  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtFirstName.Value, true);
                Response.Redirect("../index.aspx");

            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to insert some `integer` value (ex: `ID`) which gets incremented for every new record you can use `IDENTITY` column but here in your case you want to insert the default `string` value for every record so you can directly assign it in `INSERT INTO` statement.

Try This:

```
String strStatus="waiting";
string sql = "INSERT INTO appointment (aStatus,aDate, aTime, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, patientID, mcID)";
                sql += "VALUES (@aStatus,@aDate, @aTime, @aContact, @aHeight, @aWeight, @patientID, @mcID)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aStatus", strStatus);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aDate", txtDate.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aTime", txtTime.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aContact", txtContact.Value.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aHeight", txtHeight.Value.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aWeight", txtWeight.Value.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientID", txtpatientID.Value.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcID", txtmcID.Value.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the default value of the column in the database by executing this query:

```
ALTER TABLE appointment
ALTER aStatus SET DEFAULT '(waiting)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL string

```
    string sql = "INSERT INTO appointment (aDate, aTime, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, patientID, mcID, aStatus)";
```

Your values

```
    sql += "VALUES (@aDate, @aTime, @aContact, @aHeight, @aWeight, @patientID, @mcID, 'waiting')";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, like Sudhakar Tillapudi without add a parameter :

```
String strStatus="waiting";
string sql = "INSERT INTO appointment (aStatus,aDate, aTime, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, patientID, mcID)";
sql += "VALUES ('waiting',@aDate, @aTime, @aContact, @aHeight, @aWeight, @patientID, @mcID)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aDate", txtDate.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aTime", txtTime.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aContact", txtContact.Value.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aHeight", txtHeight.Value.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aWeight", txtWeight.Value.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientID", txtpatientID.Value.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcID", txtmcID.Value.Trim());
```